# Delete nested field in Firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete a nested field in Firestore but I get `FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. deleteField() can only appear at the top level of your update data`

So what I'm trying to delete is the individual fields (map) called bread, salt etc.

[image: Picture of the firestore]

```
const listRef = doc(db, "lists", list.id);
const onDismiss = useCallback(async (id: string) => {
    const onGoingIndex = onGoingItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    let getName = onGoingItems.find((item) => item.id === id)?.name || "";
 

    if (onGoingIndex !== -1) {
      onGoingItems.splice(onGoingIndex, 1);
    } else {
      const doneIndex = doneItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
      getName = doneItems.find((item) => item.id === id)?.name || "";
      doneItems.splice(doneIndex, 1);
    }

    await updateDoc(listRef, {
      items: {
        [getName]: deleteField(),
      },
    });
  }, []);
```

I've also tried using FieldValue.delete() from firebase/firestore but it has no function called delete().
[image: Error on fieldvalue]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getting access to the "field delete" operation depends on which version of the Firebase SDKs you are using:

- For v8 and older (or the v9 compatibility mode), you use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete()`.
- For v9 and newer, you use `deleteField()` (as in your case)
- For `react-native-firebase`, you currently use `firestore.FieldValue.delete()` (based on the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#removing-data), as pointed out by [@AlekssandarNikolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7784769) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70947403/3068190)).

The reason you can't use `FieldValue.delete()` is because it was removed in v9 of the SDK in favour of `deleteField()`.

However, as that error tells you, a "delete field" marker can only appear at the top level of your update data. This is because of the way Firestore handles [updating fields that are in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) to prevent the wrong data from being deleted.

With the code as you have written it, and `getName` was `"Bread"`, you would be updating the **entire** `items` object to `{ Bread: <deleteMe> }`, which would also delete `"Salt"`.

```js
await updateDoc(listRef, {
  items: {
    [getName]: deleteField(),
  },
});
```

To correct this, use dot notation of the field you want to mutate (which will correctly leave the other nested fields alone):

```js
await updateDoc(listRef, {
  [`items.${getName}`]: deleteField()
});
```

See [updating nested fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects) (and [deleting fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#fields)) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you are  using **react-native-firebase** you should probably call it like this `firestore.FieldValue.delete()`, based on the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#:%7E:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20remove%20a%20specific%20property%20with%20a%20document%2C%20rather%20than%20the%20document%20itself%2C%20you%20can%20use%20the%20delete%20method%20on%20the%20FieldValue%20class%3A)

The way to modify or delete a nested field is to generate a dot path like in the sample code.

```
const listRef = doc(db, "lists", list.id);
const onDismiss = useCallback(async (id: string) => {
    const onGoingIndex = onGoingItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    let getName = onGoingItems.find((item) => item.id === id)?.name || "";
 

    if (onGoingIndex !== -1) {
      onGoingItems.splice(onGoingIndex, 1);
    } else {
      const doneIndex = doneItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
      getName = doneItems.find((item) => item.id === id)?.name || "";
      doneItems.splice(doneIndex, 1);
    }

    await updateDoc(listRef, {
      [`items.${getName}`]: firestore.FieldValue.delete()
    });
  }, []);
```

If you are using javascript SDK. For v9 of firebase you should import it like so

```
import { deleteField } from 'firebase/firestore';


  ...

  await updateDoc(listRef, {
    [`items.${getName}`]: deleteField(),
  });
```

Comment: I'm not using react-native-firebase. I'm importing from "firebase/firestore".
In my package.json I have this verison `"firebase": "^9.6.4"`

Comment: Updated the answer to include javascript SDK solution.